# Count row with content for specific number of columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, count, sum

I can't figure out how to make a column with the count of rows with content of some other columns. **Without a count on all columns (*)**

```
-------------------------    Output should be (NO COLUMN D):    ---------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |                                       | Count |
-------------------------                                       ---------
| foo | foo | foo | foo |                                       |   9   |
-------------------------                                       ---------
| bar | bar | bar | bar |
-------------------------
|  x  |  x  |     |  x  |
-------------------------
|  y  |     |     |  y  |
-------------------------
```

I've tried many approach like :

- `SELECT SUM(COUNT(A) + Count(B) + COUNT(C)) from SomeTable`
- `SELECT COUNT(A + B + C)`
- `SELECT COUNT(A,B,C)`

I can't find the correct syntax. Can anybody help me on this one ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's was my first guess. But when I do the first one I get `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A IS  NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
     + SUM(CASE WHEN B IS  NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
     + SUM(CASE WHEN C IS  NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
     AS [TOTAL]
FROM dbo.SomeTable
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d290/3/0)

Comment: your simply great i was just trying to open my sql server and you did with a demo as well...+1

Answer (score 1):

Came across with the same error **Yesterday**. This is how i solved it.

```
Select Count(sum) from
(select 
count(A) as sum
from sometable
where ISNULL(A,'')<>''
,select 
count(B) as sum
from sometable
where ISNULL(B,'')<>''
,select 
count(C) as sum
from sometable
where ISNULL(C,'')<>''
)t
```

Comment: is the `t` a mistake at the end ?